# how to get flag and dateformates in sas

Tags: sas

Hi I have one doubt in sas
in dataset  date format have  08-04-1988
base on this values I want create  date styles and along flag values
For datetime flag creation if dateandtime have then consider flag 1 else 0 
for date if date have then consider flag 1 else 0
for time if time have then consider flag 1 else 0

```
DATA DAT;
X= "08APR1988"D;
FORMAT X DDMMYYD10.;
RUN;
```

Based on above value I want output like below

```
Datetime             | Date        | Time     |   DatetimeFlag   |  DateFlag  |TimeFlag
08APR1988 00:00:00   |08-04-1988   |00:00:00  |   0              |1           |0
```

I tried like  below

```
DATA DUMM;
SET DAT;
DT=PUT( X, DDMMYY10.);
DATEF=PUT( X, date9.);
DTs=PUT( X, DATETIME32.);
TimeF=PUT( X, TIME.);
RUN;
```

here if donot have time then its takeing default datewith time similar time also
i want display if time is not available then consider 00:00:00 similar if date not available the date aslo : 1960-01-01

but above scirpt is not given expeted result ,
can  you please tell me how to wirte sas coding to achive this task.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are the three flag variables? Where do they come from? What do they mean?  Do you mean to create them? If so what is the logic to create them?

Comment: Why are you trying to display a date value using a datetime and a time format?  It does not make sense to try to interpret the number of days since 1960 as either the number of seconds since 1960 or the number of seconds since midnight.

Answer (score 0):

SAS has two value types, numeric and character.

Date and DateTime values are numeric with handling.

Date values are the number of days since 01JAN1960.
DateTime values are the number of seconds since 01JAN1960.

Non-integer date values do not get special interpretation (in other date systems, such as Excel, the decimal part of a numeric is the fraction of the day as well)

Non-integer DateTime values are fractional seconds.

You can convert the date to datetime by multiplying by the number of seconds in a day (86,400)

Suppose you had a non-integer date value, such as

```
data _null_;
  D = '01JAN2019'D + 0.5;
  format D yymmdd10.;
  put D= / D=best12.;

  DT = D * 86400;
  format DT datetime21.2;
  put DT= / DT=best12.;
run;
---------- LOG ----------
D=2019-01-01
D=21550.5
DT=01JAN2019:12:00:00.00
DT=1861963200
```

You can separate out the date and time parts of a datetime value using the functions `DATEPART` and `TIMEPART`

```
data have;
  dt = '01FEB2019:12:34:56.78'DT; output;
  dt = '15FEB2019:00:00:00'DT; output;
  format dt datetime21.2;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  d = datepart (dt);
  t = timepart (dt);
  format d yymmdd10.;
  format t time12.2;

  dt_is_just_date  = (t eq 0);
  dt_has_time_part = (t ne 0);
run;

proc print data=want;
run;
-------
                                                              dt_is_    dt_has_
                                                               just_     time_
Obs                       dt             d               t     date       part

 1     01FEB2019:12:34:56.78    2019-02-01     12:34:56.78       0         1
 2     15FEB2019:00:00:00.00    2019-02-15      0:00:00.00       1         0
```

Comment: Note: to generate the number of seconds in a day just use the time literal for 24 hours,  `'24:00't`, no need to remember the magic number 86,400.